# PostgreSQL : Cast Data Type from Text to Bigint when using WHERE IN

Tags: postgresql

I've problem when try to cast data type from `TEXT` to `BIGINT` when using `WHERE IN` on PostgreSQL in procedure. This always gives

> operator does not exist: bigint = text. Try cast the variable in the query.

But still get the same notice. This is example query:

```
    DECLARE

     -- $1 params text

    BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM table_a where 
      colId IN($1); // notice is here, colId is bigint
    END 

    /*Call the procedure*/

    SELECT my_function('1,2,3,4,5');
```

How do we cast the variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using strings for id list is wrong design. You can use a arrays in PostgreSQL.

For example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(VARIADIC ids int[])
RETURNS SETOF table_a AS $$
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id = ANY($1)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT foo(1,2,3);
```

But, usually wrapping simple SQL to functions looks like broken design. Procedures should not to replace views.

Comment: Thanks, this method is much more scientific.

Previously sorry for the simple use of SQL, I just wanted to make it look simple and focus on the issues at hand. Despite the fact that SQL is very long. Really! thank's, you again helped solve my problem @Pavel Stehule :)

Comment: @UgyAstro use views instead this kind of functions.